# Consume Multiple API Responses into A Javascript Object in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, model-view-controller

I am trying to call two different APIs. One for location data and the other one for weather information.

I am calling these API services in my controller file. Should I use promises or async and how can I implement where I will set returned data to one single JS object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is quite vague. It would help if you would show your code, with the actual API calls, the object you try to create from them, describing what the problem is. It is not "promises **or** async": `async` is just *one* way to work with promises. Whatever you can do with `async`, you can do without. Probably the API already return promises, so you just should use them, like you would use any promise. For instance, `Promise.all` could come in handy. But make your question concrete.

Comment: `await` is blocking, so if you can run these calls in parallel, you should use `await Promise.all([promiseA,promiseB])`; you can also just chain `.then()` to the promise, but await is more modern, i guess. multiple ways to skin a cat...